# Why does ftp (via dolphin and kate) require authentication every few minutes?

Tags: 12.04, ftp

Why does ftp (via dolphin and kate) require authentication every few minutes on Kubuntu 12.04? It seems to work ok on one ftp server but not on another.

Comment: Have you tried just using the nautilus **Connect to Server** option? It is under **File**